# Start Page and the page after successful login

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to set up the right structure for my web site that uses FOSUser Bundle.. Currently, the start up page;

...app_dev.php   is the main starting page..

when the user logins,

the logged in page opens as ...app_dev.php as well..

```
_welcome:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: MyUserBundle:Welcome:index }
```

I want the initial page and logged in page to have different pages.. where do i set the page that opens after the user is logged in..  so for example, after a successful log in, i want the page to pen for example ; app_dev.php/teacher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure default_target_path

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                default_target_path: /settings
```

See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#changing-the-default-page).